# Стилизация google adsense

Tags: css, google-adsense

Можно ли стилизовать рекламные блоки `adsense`? Допустим, добавить стили непосредственно во фрейм, это возможно? Т.е. стилизовать текст рекламы.

Comment: вам нужно разместить свою рекламу или на своём сайте рекламу?

Comment: @pavel, на своём сайте нужно сделать стилизацию. Т.е. как-бы на своём, попросили сделать

Comment: используйте другой тип рекламы, например нативный (native). В баннеры лезть нельзя (вы их ещё прозрачными сделайте для повышения юзабилити).

Comment: @pavel, то что можно использовать ещё куча всего это хорошо, но мне нужно знать, это я так понял нельзя сделать?

Comment: сделать можно (технически), хотя и не так просто. Но если сеть узнает - вам будет плохо.

Comment: т.е. можно спокойно говорить клиенту, что типа нельзя сделать такое?

Comment: да. Предлагайте использовать нативку. Дизайн баннера может быть любым, повлиять вы максимум можете на контент (забанив много адвертайзеров которые разный шлак рекламируют). Ну или делайте, это возможно. Чуть что отвечать же не вы будете. Но это как в договоре прописано.

Answer (score 0):

Стилизовать текст рекламы возможно, но это делать нужно на платформе Google AdSense. Можете редактировать блоки и добавить им стили.

А добавить стили в iframe не нужно.